# Python selenium grecaptcha_cfg Callback

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

I successfully receive the recaptcha response, but since there isn't a submit button i'm thinking i need to send it via a callback.  I'm using the below command to send the response, but it's coming back as not defined and I'm not sure why.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
driver.execute_script("__grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].EL.w.callback(arguments[0]);",TOKEN_FROM_2CAPTCHA)
```

JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: __grecaptcha_cfg is not defined

Answer (score 0):

My bad I was missing an extra underscore. It should be this:

```
driver.execute_script("___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].EL.w.callback(arguments[0]);",TOKEN_FROM_2CAPTCHA)
```